# Java Regex : Replace characters between two specific characters with equal number of another character

Tags: java, regex

Replacing all characters between starting character "+" and end character "+" with the equal number of "-" characters.
My specific situation is as follows:

Input: +-+-+-+
Output: +-----+

```
String s = = "+-+-+-+";
s = s.replaceAll("-\\+-","---")
```

This is not working. How can I achieve the output in Java? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should include how it's not working. What you get instead.

Comment: If my answer did not solve your issue please consider updating the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this replacement using look around assertions:

```sh
String repl = s.replaceAll("(?<=-)\\+(?=-)", "-");
//=> +-----+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qvAFWy/1)

`(?<=-)\\+(?=-)` will match a `+` if it is surrounded by `-` on both sides. Since we are using lookbehind and lookahead therefore we are not consuming characters, these are only assertions.

Answer (score 0):

The matches you have are *overlapping*, look:

```java
+-+-+-+
 ^^^
    Match found and replaced by "---"

+---+-+
    ^
    +-- Next match search continues from here

WARNING: No more matches found!
```

To make sure there is a hyphen free for the next match, you need to wrap the trailing `-` with a [*positive lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and use `--` as replacement pattern:

```java
String s = = "+-+-+-+";
s = s.replaceAll("-\\+(?=-)","--")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vDcBsi/3).

Comment: FYI: [Here is a link](https://regex101.com/r/vDcBsi/3/debugger) to the regex debugger. If anyone wants to see how matches are now found in the current string, please click `▶️`  button.

Comment: I tried to put it into a snippet, [which works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDiv0.png). But it requires the user to both expand and run it.